# How to run the functions independently on C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a game on the console using C++. At the moment, I have three functions in the main.

```
int main() {

...

while (!level1 && !player.dead) {

    drowing(l1_map);

    PlayerMovements(empty, l1_map);

    Enemy1Movements(enemy1, l1_map, lastloc);

    cls();

  }

}
```

The first function draws the map:

```
void drowing(char l1_map[26][50]) {


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

        cout << endl;

        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {

            if (x == 0) {
                cout << " ";
            }


            //Draws the map and change colours;
            //player
            if (l1_map[i][x] == player.character) {
                if (l1_map[player.locX][player.locY] == l1_map[enemy1.locX][enemy1.locY]) {

                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 252);
                    cout << l1_map[i][x];
                }

                if (l1_map[player.locX][player.locY] != l1_map[enemy1.locX][enemy1.locY]) {

                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 250);
                    cout << l1_map[i][x];
                }

            }//wall
            else if (l1_map[i][x] == wall) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 128);
                cout << l1_map[i][x];
            }//enemy
            else if (l1_map[i][x] == enemy1.character) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 252);
                cout << l1_map[i][x];
            }//empty space
            else if (l1_map[i][x] == 32) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 509);
                cout << l1_map[i][x];
            }//key1
            else if (l1_map[i][x] == key1.character && !key1.picked) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 509);
                cout << l1_map[i][x];
            }//key2
            else if (l1_map[i][x] == key2.character && !key1.picked) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 253);
                cout << l1_map[i][x];
            }//key3
            else if (l1_map[i][x] == key3.character && !key1.picked) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 253);
                cout << l1_map[i][x];
            }//doors1
            else if (l1_map[i][x] == doors1.character) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 253);
                cout << l1_map[i][x];
            }//doors2
            else if (l1_map[i][x] == doors2.character) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 240);
                cout << l1_map[i][x];
            }//doors3
            else if (l1_map[i][x] == doors3.character) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 240);
                cout << l1_map[i][x];
            }//doors4
            else if (l1_map[i][x] == doors3.character) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 240);
                cout << l1_map[i][x];
            }//exit
            else if (l1_map[i][x] == get_out1.character && !get_out1.open) {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 139);
                cout << l1_map[i][x];

            }
            else
            {

                cout << l1_map[i][x];
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);

            }


        }

    }

}
```

Second function allows player to move on the map using keyboard arrows:

```
void PlayerMovements(char& empty, char l1_map[26][50]) {



    char awall = 219;

    if (_kbhit()) {


        switch ((_getch())) { //what button is pressed;


                              // move up
        case 72:

            if (l1_map[player.locX - 1][player.locY] != wall && l1_map[player.locX - 1][player.locY] != '[') {

                player.locX--;


                if (l1_map[player.locX + 1][player.locY] == player.character) {

                    l1_map[player.locX + 1][player.locY] = empty;

                }

                if (key3.locX == player.locX && key3.locY == player.locY) {

                    l1_map[key3.locX][key3.locY] = ' ';

                }

            }



            break;

            //move down

        case 80:


            if (l1_map[player.locX + 1][player.locY] != wall && l1_map[player.locX + 1][player.locY] != '[') {

                player.locX++;

                if (l1_map[player.locX - 1][player.locY] == player.character) {

                    l1_map[player.locX - 1][player.locY] = empty;

                }



            }

            break;

        case 75:

            //left
            if (l1_map[player.locX][player.locY - 1] != wall  && l1_map[player.locX][player.locY - 1] != '[') {

                player.locY--;


                if (l1_map[player.locX][player.locY + 1] == player.character) {


                    l1_map[player.locX][player.locY + 1] = empty;

                }

            }


            break;


        case 77: // player moves right

            if (l1_map[player.locX][player.locY + 1] != wall && l1_map[player.locX][player.locY + 1] != '[') {

                player.locY++;

                if (l1_map[player.locX][player.locY - 1] = player.character) {

                    l1_map[player.locX][player.locY - 1] = empty;
                }



            }

            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Third function is the enemy that moves up and down:

```
int Enemy1Movements(enemy& enemy1, char l1_map[26][50], char& lastloc) {

    //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
    char empty = ' ';

    bool ValidUp = false;
    bool ValidDown = false;
    bool ValidLeft = false;
    bool ValidRight = false;



    if (l1_map[enemy1.locX + 1][enemy1.locY] != wall && l1_map[enemy1.locX + 1][enemy1.locY] != '-') {

        ValidDown = true;
    }
    if (l1_map[enemy1.locX - 1][enemy1.locY] != wall && l1_map[enemy1.locX - 1][enemy1.locY] != '-') {
        ValidUp = true;
    }
    if (l1_map[enemy1.locX][enemy1.locY - 1] != wall && l1_map[enemy1.locX - 1][enemy1.locY] != '-') {
        ValidLeft = true;
    }
    if (l1_map[enemy1.locX][enemy1.locY + 1] != wall && l1_map[enemy1.locX + 1][enemy1.locY] != '-') {
        ValidRight = true;
    }


    ////enemy move up and down
    //////////////////////////


    if (lastloc != 'u' && ValidDown) {


        enemy1.locX++;
        lastloc = 'd';




        if (l1_map[enemy1.locX - 1][enemy1.locY] == enemy1.character) {

            l1_map[enemy1.locX - 1][enemy1.locY] = 32;

        }

    }
    else if (lastloc == 'd' && ValidUp) {

        enemy1.locX--;
        lastloc = 'u';


        if (l1_map[enemy1.locX + 1][enemy1.locY] == enemy1.character) {

            l1_map[enemy1.locX + 1][enemy1.locY] = 32;

        }


    }
    else {

        if (ValidUp) {

            enemy1.locX--;
            lastloc = 'u';


            if (l1_map[enemy1.locX + 1][enemy1.locY] == enemy1.character) {

                l1_map[enemy1.locX + 1][enemy1.locY] = 32;

            }

        }
        else {

            enemy1.locX++;
            lastloc = 'd';

            if (l1_map[enemy1.locX - 1][enemy1.locY] == enemy1.character) {

                l1_map[enemy1.locX - 1][enemy1.locY] = 32;

            }



        }
    }



    return NULL;



}
```

**What I am tryng to achieve:**

I need to slow down the `EnemyMovemens()` function, because the enemy moves to fast. Or to make `PlayerMovements()` function independent from other functions.

**The Problem:**

I have tried to use threads. Functions like `this_thread::sleep_for()` and `Sleep()`. To put them in `EnemyMovements()` function. In that case, it slow down all app and my player moves very slowly.

I dont need a code, because I love to learn by myself. I just need a guidance what direction to move now.

**OS: Win 10**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that you don't having any timing in your game loop so everything is happening at the same speed.  There are some good articles online that discuss game timing loops, this one for  instance: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/ walks you through the steps from the approach you're using now to the better approach of separating your game update timing from your display timing.

That article doesn't tell you how to slow your enemy down relative to your player - one approach is to have a enemySpeed variable and use something like:

```
// outside main loop
int enemySlowness = 20;  // adjust this as needed
int enemyMoveTimer = 0;

...
if (++enemyMoveTimer > enemySlowness)
{
    Enemy1Movements(enemy1, l1_map, lastloc);
    enemyMoveTime = 0;
}
```

There are problems with this approach, but coupled with some idea from that article should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is solved my problem. The link is very useful aswell. I have improved my game already :)